# Can I rely on the order of imports when building client side code using webpack?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I am implementing webpack on an existing code base where various javascript libraries are imported using separate script tags. Some of this libraries rely on global variables (some declared on window) declared in libraries included beforehand.

If i use import statement to include these libraries into a master script will the order in output package be the same as my imports, for libraries that don't declare dependencies on each other?

I have read some things which tend to indicate that it may be better to use require instead of import int this case

I am aware that it may be better to do shimming in the long run but I want to avoid having to do everything in one go

Comment: Yes, the order of imports is preserved.

Comment: Notice that `import`ed files are treated as modules, so declaring global variables might not work the same as it did before.

Comment: It's *always* a good idea for a module to declare its dependencies. Just add them, and you won't need to worry about the order of imports in your master script.

Comment: @Bergi - For modules that I'm writing imports and exports are declared but I have a number external dependencies which use globals. I can satisfy some of the dependencies using the provide plugin but am not sure if there is easy way to deal with modules which provide or expect variables on window. I want to get things working and then look at libraries one by one to see if things can be done better.